# Does Gmail automatically exclude emails with similar content?

Tags: email, gmail, sendgrid

I am trying to send very similar emails to 2 Gmail addresses that should end up in the same inbox:
"example@gmail.com"
"example+1@gmail.com"

However, I don't get consistent results. Sometimes both emails are received, but most often only 1 is in the inbox (the one that was sent first). The "Spam" folder is clear as well, so the second email just "disappears".
Also, I don't face any issues when trying to send these emails to different addresses.

The delay between sending them is minimal, I am using SendGrid's personalizations, so both emails are sent in 1 request.

I wonder whether this issue could be caused by some Gmail functionality that excludes similar emails in 1 inbox.

Comment: What do your SendGrid logs or other available logs say? If the two emails have the same status, response codes, or what have you, it's likely a Gmail problem. What is the function of the application you're building, a mailing list I assume?